# Use send to generator with itertools.tee

Tags: python, generator, python-itertools, python-3.6

I am trying to split a generator with `send` and [itertools.tee](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee).  While this works for a generator without `send`, this example yields the following error:

> AttributeError: 'itertools._tee' object has no attribute 'send'

```
from itertools import tee


def i():
    for j in range(10):
        yield j
        x = yield


k = i()
k.send(None)
next(k)

l1, l2 = tee(k)
next(l1)
l1.send(None)
```

Is there any workaround or other methods to split a generator. (Making a list or not using a generator is not an option here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any workaround or other methods to split a generator.

Regular (one-way) generators work easily with [*itertools.tee()*](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) or a pure python equivalent.

However, two-way generators (where you push in data with `g.send(x)` and receive it with `x = yield y`) aren't splittable.

The reason is that tee-like splits essentially buffer-up previously reported results to re-use on each of the split-offs.  But a two-way iterator can't reuse previous results because it is sending in new values which can affect future calls.

Accordingly, the whole concept of splitting a stream stops making sense when you can push data back in from either of the split streams which can each have advanced to different places.

Answer (score -1):

Your code for `i()` yields first, then accept `x` later. That means you need to call `next()` first, then `send()`.

Comment: I have been trying to swap around `next()` and `send`, but this does not seem to work. Could you give me an example?

Comment: I cannot, I have never written code that both yield and accepting yield at the same time. All I did was to take your example and tried `next()` first, then `send()`

Comment: I deserve the down vote. I thought I would comment on your post, but forgot and made that into an answer :(